# Passing JSON from Spring Controller to React

Tags: json, spring, reactjs

I try to pass a JSON as String from my Spring Controller to the React Frontend.

***JSON:***

```
{
  "name": ".",
  "size": 0,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "setup.bat",
      "size": 6,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "src",
      "size": 0,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "main",
          "size": 0,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "java",
              "size": 0,
              "children": [
...
```

I try it with Thymeleaf and the console output on my site worked:

***index.html***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var jsondata = /*[[${jsondata}]]*/;
   console.debug(jsondata);
});
```

but now i try to used it in react I get an error:

***app.js:***

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {jsondata}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsondata is not defined

What is the Problem in React ?

Comment: because you haven't defined it in the React file? :/

Comment: @illiteratewriter but can i say that he should use the js var ? because i cant use thymeleaf in react, this makes an error

Comment: You should import your json data with `import jsondata from '<relative_path_of_the_json_file>';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I can use the Javascript var with my React code, but the Problem was in my html file. I make a wrong order of the scripts.

If i use the React bundle at the end it works:

**index.html:**

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
   var jsondata = /*[[${jsonHierarchy}]]*/;
   console.log(jsondata);
</script>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set and access the JSON on directly on the `window` object.

```
window.jsondata = /*[[${jsondata}]]*/;

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {window.jsondata}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```